# Live Preview Vs code Extension

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, github

After installing the live server preview extension on vs code, I've been trying to live preview my html AND Javascript content.

But as soon as I click on "Go live" it shows

> Error on port 5500. Please try to change the port through settings or report on GitHub.

I did check the Github report , it said I should change the settings to `liveServer.settings.port:0(or whatever)` but the thing is I don't really know where that setting is and how I can access it, please any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your settings through File->Preferences->Settings. There you can search for the setting you'd like to change.

Answer (score 1):

In your VSCode user settings add this line,

```
"liveServer.settings.port":8080,
```

For more info, you can check the [Docs](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/docs/settings.md) on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Open the window power shell as admin and execute the command:

```
command 1:netstat -ano | findstr :5500
```

Then, you will get a message like:

> TCP 0.0.0.0:5500  0.0.0.0 #webpage name# #port_number

Afterwards, execute:

```
command 2:taskkill /PID port_number /F
```